# Timestamp and date in Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I apologize in advance for my English.
So, I want search between by dates in Hibernate Search. But, in database date is as timestamp without time zone. In my model as date:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Field
@DateBridge(resolution = Resolution.MILLISECOND)
@Column(name = "iat_date", nullable = false/*, length = 13*/)
public Date getIatDate() {
    return iatDate;
}
```

And query:

```
Query query = queryBuilder.range().onField("iatDate").ignoreFieldBridge()
.from(DateTools.dateToString(dateFrom, DateTools.Resolution.MILLISECOND))
.to(DateTools.dateToString(dateTo, DeTools.Resolution.MILLISECOND))
.createQuery();
```

And it doesn't work. I dont know why. Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: No errors. Just no results found.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate Search? Remember: recent versions will encode the Date as a Numeric Field by default, so you should create a numeric range query. Easiest would be to check the index structure using Luke.